# Calling erase with iterator vs const_iterator

Tags: c++, data-structures

Why does calling the `erase` member function of a container with a `const_iterator` fail?

It works with a non const `iterator`.

Comment: for example, because this is a **const**_iterator ?

Comment: How exactly did you *defile* the iterator? The poor thing :)

Comment: This issue seems to be thought as a defect of current standard.
In C++0x `erase` member functions of standard containers take const_iterator.

Answer (score 30):

This doesn't compile because `container::iterator` and `container::const_iterator` are two distinct types and the only (one-argument) version of erase is: `iterator erase(iterator);`

Not accepting a `const_iterator` can be viewed as a defect in the language standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2350.pdf

There is no particular reason for this restriction. The iterator is only used to **indicate a position** in the (modifiable) container, and neither in case of `insert` or `erase` is the "pointee" of the iterator modified (in case of `erase` it just conceptually goes out of existence, which is a normal thing to do for const objects).

Current standard indicates a confusion between "iterator constness and container constness" (as do other answers here), and it seems `const_iterator` might become acceptable for `erase` in C++0x.

---

As a workaround, you can validly obtain an `iterator` from a `const_iterator` because the container has to be mutable in the first place.

The function below is only compilable for random access iterators, as it might be a bit too slow to do this with other types of iterators.

```
#include <vector>

template <class Container>
typename Container::iterator to_mutable_iterator(Container& c, typename Container::const_iterator it)
{
    return c.begin() + (it - c.begin());
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1};
    std::vector<int> vec(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ) {
        //if (*it = 5) {  //const_iterator prevents this error
        if (*it == 5) {
            it = vec.erase(to_mutable_iterator(vec, it));
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it might be better to restructure code so that you don't need a `const_iterator` in the first place. In this case, it would be better to use the `std::remove` algorithm. If you need to do more non-mutating work before erasing, you can extract that into a separate method etc.

Comment: Worth nothing that since C++11 `erase` does have overload for `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 6):

I just want to emphasize on the general correctness of the answers/comments posted by UncleBens, David Rodriguez, and Ise Westeria.

Regardless of the behaviors of the current (or previous) pre-C++11 compilers, the const correctness of const_iterator (should) stops immediately at that it semantically equals to const T* (or T* const) - note that T itself might be a const type of its own! - so it effectively prevents code modifying the referenced object in the container.

However, as it is perfectly legal to 'delete' a const pointer in C++ (try it, it works!), it should be (and the behavior has been corrected in C++11) legal as well to 'erase" a const iterator from a container, provided the container itself is not const.

It seems Visual Studio 2010 is already behaving correctly by having 'erase' accepting const_iterator, which of course caused me some headaches to track down some other bug, which led me to this post, which eventually clarified the correct behavior of "erase const_iterator" const correctness.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding constness, you can think of a `std::container<T>::const_iterator` as a `const T*`.

Comment: Since you were picky with the original question I will be picky with the answer :P, "but I can `delete` a `const T*`". Seriously, I don't think this question adds much value, the fact that access to the contained element is `const` does not necessarily imply that you could not modify the container itself.

Comment: @David: I just thought I'd mention `const T*` because many beginners seem to think that a `const_iterator` is actually more like a `T* const`.

Answer (score 1):

A type `const_iterator` cannot be used to modify the value of an element or the container.

Comment: I agree. So there is no way to erase entry with const_iterator?

Comment: Yes. That's what `const_iterator` is for. Just given access rights but no modification rights.

Comment: Interestingly at least in N3092 for C++0x, containers' erase and insert methods indeed take `const_iterator` - there is no particular reason why one shouldn't be good for those methods, except perhaps for the `const_cast` hackery that might be needed to implement them. As long as the container is modifyable, I'm not modifying the referenced item, I'm *only* invalidating the iterator (which happens with `const_iterator` all the time).

Comment: Deletion is not the same as modification in C++.