# map erase error

Tags: c++, dictionary, erase

i have wriitten program for diffrent operations on maps.

and a sample code of my program is given below.

while running this code i am getting an error like map erase out of range exception.

please help me to solve this.

```
  int main( )
  {
    using namespace std;
    map <int, int> m1;

    map <int, int> :: iterator m1_Iter;
    map <int, int> :: const_iterator m1_cIter;
    typedef pair <int, int> Int_Pair;

    m1.insert ( Int_Pair ( 1, 10 ) );
    m1.insert ( Int_Pair ( 2, 20 ) );
    m1.insert ( Int_Pair ( 3, 30 ) );

    m1_cIter = m1.end( );
    m1_cIter--;
    cout << "The value of the last element of m1 is:\n" 
      << m1_cIter -> second << endl;

    m1_Iter = m1.end( );
    m1_Iter--;
    m1.erase ( m1_Iter );

            m1_cIter = m1.begin( );
    m1_cIter--;
    m1.erase ( m1_cIter );

    m1_cIter = m1.end( );
    m1_cIter--;
    cout << "The value of the last element of m1 is now:\n"
      << m1_cIter -> second << endl;
    getchar();
  }
```

Comment: You should try to add some debug `cout`s in your code to help trace down your problem. We typically do not debug your code for you. Identify the problem and then ask the question.

Comment: i am getting a run time error in this part


            m1_cIter = m1.begin( ); 
    m1_cIter--; 
    m1.erase ( m1_cIter );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885318/calling-erase-with-iterator-vs-const-iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to erase the element located **before** your first element, what would this point to?

---

Relevant snippet from posted code:

```
 m1_cIter = m1.begin( );
 m1_cIter--;
 m1.erase ( m1_cIter );
```

---

**A side note** is that I'm finding it quite odd that you are able to compile and run the provided snippet at all.

It should give you errors regarding the fact that you cannot erase an element through a `std::map<int,int>::const_iterator`, which is the type of `m1_cIter`.

Comment: @0A0D but not a `const_iterator`. a `const_iterator` should/cannot be used to modify the element inside a container.

Comment: Yes, but there is a workaround. It's a defect in the language itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885318/calling-erase-with-iterator-vs-const-iterator

Answer (score 1):

```
m1_cIter = m1.begin();
m1_cIter --;
```

is undefined behavior.  Did you mean

```
m1_cIter = m1.end();
m1_cIter --;
```

Answer (score 0):

`m1.erase ( m1_cIter );`

This could be the problem because `m1_cIter` is a `const_iterator`. The code will not compile.

After commenting this line, I get this output:

```
 ./maptest
The value of the last element of m1 is:
30
The value of the last element of m1 is now:
20
```

Also in your code:

```
m1_cIter = m1.begin( );
m1_cIter--;
```

This could be undefined behavior, not guaranteed to work always.