# Why const_iterator could be used with std::map::erase

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdmap, const-iterator

I was under the impression one cant use `erase` on a `const iterator`. Check [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885318/calling-erase-with-iterator-vs-const-iterator).
Why does the below code compile (C++11, gcc)?

```
long getMax(const bool get_new)
{
    long max_val=0;

    TO now=getNow();

    map<TO, long>& m=get_new?m_new:m_old;

    for(auto it=m.cbegin(); it !=m.cend())
    {
        if(now.compareTime((*it).first)<lookback)
        {
            max_val=max(max_val,
                        (*it).second);
            ++it;
        }
        else
        {
            it=m.erase(it);
        }
    }

    return max_val;
}
```

The [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) itself is not constant, but my understanding is that the `const iterator` should make this fail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The behavior has changed from C++11; [std::map::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) takes `const_iterator` as its parameter.

```
void erase( iterator pos );           // (until C++11)
iterator erase( const_iterator pos ); // (since C++11)
iterator erase( iterator pos );       // (since C++17)
```

For `std::map::erase`, the passed iterator is just used as the position where the element would be deleted, not for modifying the element through it. That means `const_iterator` would be fine. Before C++11, the support for `const_iterator` was not very good, but the situation has changed from C++11. You should use `const_iterator` instead of `iterator` when possible now.

Answer (score 9):

Positions are independent of the constness of their access. It was (is?) quite common that functions doing a search return `const_iterator` because they actually do not change the container at all. However, it is desirable to use the obtained position for mutations of the sequences, e.g., to `insert()` an element at the corresponding position or to `erase()` the located element. As a result, the container where extended to support use of `const_iterator` with mutating operations.

It seems the relevant paper is [N2350](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2350.pdf). I'm not sure if this paper is the latest version.