# LInux g++ compiler errors on vector iterator when Visual Studio runs just fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, iterator, g++

I have successfully compiled a C++ file allocation program on Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with no issues. However, when I try to compile the same program on a Red Hat Linux server with GCC 4.8.5, I get errors that hound on the vector/iterator I'm using. Here is the nested struct and the type my vector is using:

```
    struct FATPtr
{
    string filename;
    int fileByte;

    bool operator< (const FATPtr& other) const          // overloaded < operator to compare two FAT pointers;
    {                                                   // comparison is by filename
        return filename < other.filename;
    }

    bool operator< (const string& fname) const          // overloaded < operator to compare FAT pointer filename
    {                                                   // to another filename
        return filename < fname;
    }
};

FATPtr fatPtr;                                          // pointer to a file allocation table entry
vector<FATPtr> fatVector;                               // vector to hold these pointers
```

And here is the code generating the errors:

```
    // insert FAT filename and location into sorted vector
fatPtr.filename = filename;
fatPtr.fileByte = fatByte;
auto at = lower_bound(fatVector.cbegin(), fatVector.cend(), filename);
fatVector.insert(at, fatPtr);

void DiskInterface::deleteFATEntry(Disk& dsk, string filename, int entry)
{
    auto at = lower_bound(fatVector.cbegin(), fatVector.cend(), filename);
    fatVector.erase(at);

    dsk.writeFAT(entry);
}
```

Specifically, the "at" iterator is throwing the error in both the vector insert and erase methods:

```
{cslinux1:~/CS4348/Project3} g++ -std=c++0x Project3.cpp -o Project3
Project3.cpp: In member function ‘void DiskInterface::addFAT(Disk&, std::string, int, int)’:
Project3.cpp:248:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<DiskInterface::FATPtr>::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const DiskInterface::FATPtr*, std::vector<DiskInterface::FATPtr> >&, DiskInterface::FATPtr&)’
  fatVector.insert(at, fatPtr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC 4.8.5 could not handle const iterators in `std::vector::insert` and `std::vector::erase` ([The GNU C++ Library Manual -  1.1 Implementation Status - 23.3.6](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html)):

Change your calls to `cbegin()` and `cend()` to `begin()` and `end()`.

```
auto at = lower_bound(fatVector.begin(), fatVector.end(), filename);
```

Your code compiles fine with later versions.

Looks like [defect in the language standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888697/8918119) as @UncleBens points ([Container insert/erase and iterator constness(Revision 1)) N2350](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2350.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you, indeed, @A. A , the change worked and I definitely appreciate the reference!