# Why were the std::vector::erase parameters changed to const_iterator?

Tags: c++

According to e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase the parameters to `std::vector::erase` were in C++11 changed from `iterator` to `const_iterator`.

This is surprising; logically, the container does have to change the data pointed to by those iterators, and indeed when I implemented my own vector class, the compiler complained that I was calling `memmove` with a const pointer; I fixed it by changing the parameters back to `iterator`.

What's the logic behind making them `const_iterator`?

Comment: The erase function is still nonconst, but you can call it now with a const iterator. erase doesn't actually use the content of the iterator more than to calculate an offset and then a pointer really.

Comment: erase doesn't modify the thing being erased

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888697/3585576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator just says where.  The vector is non-const, and is from which it is erased.

This lets you find the location to be erased in a cost manner, and only when you actually erase it do you need a non const container.